# Library abs with Fragment sample

Tags: android

I am using lib abs at actionbarsherlock.com/ in Esclipse

I can import sucessfully with sample in api.github.com/repos/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/zipball/4.4.0

include : 
actionbarsherlock-samples/demos
actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments
actionbarsherlock-samples/known-bugs
actionbarsherlock-samples/roboguice
actionbarsherlock-samples/styled

I run and build projects sucessfully but with actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments have bug.

Bug error in logcat :

1. fragment_tabs.xml

> [2014-10-28 02:12:06 - SampleList] D:\Esclipe\src\SampleList\res\layout\fragment_tabs.xml:46: note: did you mean to use @+id instead of @+android:id?
>   [2014-10-28 02:12:06 - SampleList] D:\Esclipe\src\SampleList\res\layout\fragment_tabs.xml:46: error: creating resource for external package android: id/realtabcontent.
>   [2014-10-28 02:12:06 - SampleList] D:\Esclipe\src\SampleList\res\layout\fragment_tabs.xml:46: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@+android:id/realtabcontent').

I checked R.java in gen folder but nothing in gen folder.

2. I try delete android-support-v4.jar in libs folder => all file load Successfull but LoaderThrottleSupport.java is bug

> lh5.googleusercontent.com/-HhDme8oyJ8Y/VE6a0LTS-MI/AAAAAAAAAco/bJvXyRkCzEU/s320/2.png
>   
>   work done:

- add lib : actionbarsherlock
- delete android-support-v4.jar

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If `realtabcontent` is a view that you are defining, then you want **@+id**/realtabcontent. Remove the `android:` part.

If you are referencing something from the Android framework, then you'd use **@android:**{some resource}

Answer (score 3):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/0f2beb1%5E!/
according to the fix link above, you should remove the **android:** prefix relatively

May this help:)